# ¿Cómo escanear un documento en QT?

Tags: c++, qt, impresión, scanner

Estoy realizando un proyecto por aplicación de C++ en Qt, en el cual puedo buscar un archivo en especifico, lo subo y lo imprimo de la siguiente manera:

```
void Principal::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    imagefilename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this,"Image to open","","Images (*.bmp *.png *.xpm *.*)");
    QImage   QImagen;
    QImagen.load (imagefilename);
    ui->Image1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImagen));

}

void Principal::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QFileInfo prue(imagefilename);
    LPCSTR imprimir;
    imprimir=(LPCSTR)imagefilename.toStdString().c_str();
    ShellExecuteA(0,"print",imprimir,"",imprimir,1);
}
```

He buscado información para poder escanear un documento de una impresora y no he encontrado nada. Mi pregunta es: Si con esta función de QPrinter y QPrintDialog, se puede realizar la función de escanear, y si no, cual es alguna alternativa para poder escanear en C++. 
Pueden comentar cualquier duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando la función, lo que conseguí fue poder escanear abriendo el ejecutable de la impresora, que depende donde este en cada computadora.

```
ShellExecuteA(0,"Abrir","Ubicación","","",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay, hasta donde sé, herramientas de escaneado en Qt. Supongo que el motivo principal es que no hay un estándar definido para gestionar el escaneo y cada fabricante lo hace a su manera.

Para hacer lo que pretendes puedes echar un vistazo al siguiente [proyecto](https://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/). Está basado en Qt así que debería poder adaptarse a tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, creo que habia leido algo de Twain. ¿Es una aplicación?
Otra pregunta pero en QT, tu crees que por ShellExecute pueda abrir mi ejecutable donde tengo el escaner de la impresora y así poder escanear.

Comment: @JoséT. Podrías ejecutar la aplicación del escáner, pero salvo que la misma pueda ser configurada vía argumentos dudo que puedas automatizar el escaneo y el usuario únicamente verá que se le abre la app del escáner como si la hubiese abierto él mismo